# Is the product of 2 square roots of negative numbers a negative or positive value???

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, products

I couldn't quite tell if the product of two square roots of negative numbers in ℂ (complex numbers) should be a positive real number or a negative one.. and this is because of the following two possibilities of solving that.

For example:

```
√−4×√−9=√(2i)²×√(3i)²
   =|2i|×|3i|
   =|6i²|
   =|−6|
   =6
```

Or

```
√−4×√−9=√(2i)²×√(3i)²
   =2i×3i
   =6i²
   =−6
```

So which one is correct and why?

Comment: The second is correct. In the first one you’re using the incorrect definition of the absolute value of a complex number

Comment: Oh I see.. can you tell me more about the correct definition of the absolute value?

Comment: Um... those are *both* real numbers.  A negative number *is* a real number.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake guys.. I edited it.. I meant to ask whether it is a positive or negative, and not real or complex!!

Comment: My answer on a similar question gives you a good idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4849127/267917

Answer (score 3):

Your dilemma comes from using the square root symbol as if it singled out a particular complex number, but that's not the case.

When $a$ is real and positive the equation
$$
x^2 = a
$$
has two real solutions. Just one of those is positive, and we call that one $\sqrt{a}$. The other one is 
$-\sqrt{a}$.

When $a$ is negative it has two complex square roots but there is no reasonable consistent way to call one of them
$\sqrt{a}$, so that expression isn't used.

So for example both $2i$ and $-2i$ square to $-4$ but neither of them is "the" square root. Similarly, $1-i$ and $-1+i$ each square to $-2i$ but neither of them is "the" square root.

Comment: Oh yes.. you are right!! How come that I missed that point .. so we say that sqrt(-4)=|2|i or what?

Comment: You missed the point: "that expression", namely the expression sqrt(-4), "isn't used".

Comment: I am working with complex numbers here.. that's why it is used

Comment: what is "the" square root of a negative number?

Comment: @orangeskid Sometimes $i$ rather than $-i$ is considered  "the" square root of $-1$ but in general there is no preferred root of a complex number that isn't real and positive.

Comment: I see, thank you. But if we consider this root function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ we cannot make it multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Ethan's answer: Beginners sometimes write things like "$\sqrt{-4}=\pm2i$", but this isn't actually an equation; it's shorthand for the sentence "If $z^2=-4$, then $z=2i$ or $z=-2i$".

You shouldn't do algebra with an expression like $\sqrt{-4}$ that doesn't denote exactly one number, because you'll quickly lose track of the "or".

For example, say we know that $a^2=-1$ and $b^2=-1$.

Is it possible that $a\times b=1$? Yes, because we could have $a=i$ and $b=-i$.

Is it possible that $a\times a=1$? No, because this is $a^2$, which we've assumed is $-1$.

But if you write $a=\sqrt{-1}$ and $b=\sqrt{-1}$ and substitute these "values" into the expressions above, then you get "$\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}$" for both, and you've lost information. The best way to avoid this kind of confusion is to explicitly keep track of the cases instead of trying to use "$\sqrt{}$" (or "$\pm$") expressions to denote multiple values at once.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. So the first expression is not correct. But that's what I was given in an exercise: √-4×√-9+√-2×√-8 and the answer is supposed to be -10 and I couldn't understand how they got this.. can you pleaaaase explain to me how? (If it's possible to solve it of course)

Comment: @SabrineBina We can't explain how this is the answer since the person who wrote the question did not really understand the subtlety of complex square roots and made some assumptions that work sometimes but not always.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation