# I am having a doubt in complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

A question in my text book states as follows:

> Find all possible values of $\sqrt i + \sqrt{-i}$.

Firsly I found the value of $\sqrt i$ which came out to be $\pm(1/\sqrt 2 + i(1/\sqrt 2))$.
Then I wrote $\sqrt{-i}$ as $\sqrt{-1} \sqrt{i}  = i\sqrt{i}$.
So the given expression became $\sqrt{i} (1+i)$.
In this I put the two values of $\sqrt{i}$ and hence got $2$ answers.
But the textbook states $4$ answers for this question.
Can you please let me know in which step I am wrong.

Comment: Just a remark: in general, $\sqrt{ab}\neq \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ for complex $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 4):

Your textbook is wrong:

For real numbers ($a \in \mathbb{R}$), the expression $\sqrt{a}$ makes sense:

$b = \sqrt{a} \iff b \ge 0 \text{ and } b^2=a$

For complex numbers, this is impossible because the expression $c \ge 0$ does not make sense, hence the term $\sqrt{a}$ does not make sense for complex numbers, hence the term $\sqrt{i}$ does not make sense.

Yet, the expression gets used sometimes, and in fact it means that the person is looking for $x$, for which: $x^2=i$.

As you know, the equation $x^2=i$ has two solutions for $x$, and also the equation $x^2=-i$ has two solutions, so there should be four solutions for $x^2=i \text{ or } x^2=-i$, and honestly I believe you already found all solutions:

For $x^2=i$, you have found two solutions:

1. $x_1=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$
2. $x_2=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$

You said yourself that, in order to find the solutions of $x^2=-i$, you just multiply the solutions by $i$, so let's to that:

3. $x_3 = i \cdot x_1 = i \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(i-1)$
4. $x_4 = i \cdot x_2 = i \cdot (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(i-1)$

Answer (score 2):

Call $x=\sqrt i-\sqrt{-i}$. Then
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x-\sqrt{i}=\sqrt{-i}\\
x^2-2\sqrt{i}x+i=-i\\
x^2+2i=2\sqrt{i}x\\
x^4+4ix^2-4=4ix^2,
\end{array}
$$
thus $x$ is any of the roots of $x^4-4$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{-1}$ can be $\pm i$ and therefore you get 4 answers corresponding to all the combinations of $\pm$ in your two terms

Comment: How is √(-1) equal to (-i)?

Comment: @MadhavMittal Because $(-i)^2 = -1$, just as $i^2 = -1$, so they are both square roots of $-1$. (This confusion of yours is pretty common, and it's one big reason I generally try to  discourage people from using square root symbols on numbers that aren't non-negative reals.)